# How to display the input box of a particular div when a value is selected from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I have a div repeating many times, containing a select box which has one value *Advanced*. When I am slecting that value in the dropdown of the particular div, I want to display an input box corresponding to that div.

```
<div >

<select name="skilltest">

         <option value="advanced">Avanced</option> 

</select>

<input type="text" class="disableskill"/>

</div>
```

I have written a jquery script to display the input box as shown below :

```
$("select.skilltest").change(function()
{
    var skillvalue=$(this).val();

    if(skillvalue == "Advanced" || skillvalue  == "advanced")
    {
        $(".disableskill").show();
    }
    else{

        $(".disableskill").hide();
    }
});
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: I'd take a look at selecting siblings in jQuery https://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Comment: Why not use a checkbox? What is the point of having a select list with only one option?

Comment: @SamOnela Perhaps there is the possibility of more options being added in the future, or maybe they just don't want to deal with specifying logic on the server for unchecked boxes. Can't blame him, personally. Checkboxes are sort of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next() function to select the next element from $(this):

```js
$("select[name=skilltest]").change(function(){
  var skillvalue=$(this).val();
  if(skillvalue == "Advanced" || skillvalue  == "advanced"){
    $(this).next(".disableskill").show();
  } else{
    $(this).next(".disableskill").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select name="skilltest">
    <option>--please select--</option>
    <option value="advanced">Avanced</option> 
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="disableskill" style="display:none;"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. With the next() method you can hide or show the next input.

```js
$(".skilltest").change(function()
{
    var skillvalue = $(this).val();
    if(skillvalue == "Advanced" || skillvalue  == "advanced")
    {
        $(this).next(".disableskill").show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).next(".disableskill").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <select class="skilltest">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="advanced">Avanced</option> 
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="disableskill" style="display:none"/>
</div>

<div>
  <select class="skilltest">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="advanced">Avanced</option> 
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="disableskill" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following script without extra condition in IF block

```
$(".skilltest").change(function()
{
    var skillvalue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if(skillvalue  == "advanced")
    {
        $(".disableskill").show();
    }
    else{
        $(".disableskill").hide();
    }
});
```